# How to handle a Google security warning to a non Google email address?

Tags: email, google, spam

I just received two emails from Google. The first one tells me that my password was changed, the second one tells me, that a windows device logged in to my account.

All the links in the emails point to a google domain (*.google.com) and they use my correct first and surname.

But what really confuses me, is that the warning is for a non-Google email address (***@gmx.de), I cannot log in to Google with this email address and I'm using 2FA.

Is this spam? What's the point if they don't trick me to give out my password?

Here are the screenshots of the emails. I received the emails from no-reply@accounts.google.com

[image]

> Hello Alexander,
>   The password for your Google Account *****@gmx.de has been changed recently.
>   This activity is unknown to you?
>   Learn more about restoring your account here.

[image]

> Someone signed in to your Google Account through a new Windows device. You have received this email because we want to make sure that this is you.

Comment: Someone may have put your email address as a recovery address for their Google Apps (or whatever it's currently called - custom domain Gmail) address, which could result in this, although I wouldn't normally expect the correct name, unless you have a common name and a good Gmail identity for that name (https://xkcd.com/1279/)

Comment: The email address doesn't contain my name. Is there a way to find out which app uses this email address?

Comment: When signed into Google, visit https://myaccount.google.com/security and you should find an option for currently associated apps and devices, which you could check for unexpected activity. Don't know if that would help for an erroneously associated account though.